# How to deflate only red buildings in Leaflet (L.Deflate plugin)

Tags: leaflet

I want the L.Deflate plug-in to be applied only to red buildings.

Created **L.featureGroup()** and put red buildings there, but Deflate does not work.

This code works for all buildings:

```
L.Deflate({minSize: 10).addTo(map);
```

If I try to put red buildings in this layer, Deflate does not work:

```
L.Deflate({minSize: 10, featureGroup: group_red}).AddTo(map);
```

how can I do this and is it possible, is it at all?

here JSfiddle, demonstrating the problem (uncomment line 15)

https://jsfiddle.net/petrovnn/65y1ed8w/